# Firebase~ Facebook login after being initially created

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am able to go through FBSDKLoginManager and create and store a new user in my Firebase database with the help of the "signInWithCredential" method.

However once the user leaves the app, I am having trouble finding the right method to log them back in.

this is sort of what i have....

```
static func loginUser(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

    user?.linkWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        completion(success: true)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replicating my Facebook signUp method which kind of works out a little better where every time the user runs the app, I will call FBSDKGraphRequest and get the latest changes to the user's profile.